# How to access the angular variable in script tag

Tags: angular, typescript

How to access the angular variable tracking ID(UA-123XXXXXX-1) in script tag

```
<app-root></app-root>
<script>
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);

        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-123XXXXXX-1', 'auto');// add your tracking ID here.
ga('send', 'pageview');


</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, I do not understand. Are you trying to add google analytics to your angular application? if so, you don't add angular references there. The script that you added was fine. The rest of the code should e in your bootstrapped component. Appcomponent

Comment: @TaranjitKang  , i want to set this UA-123XXXXXX-1 variable from angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4+ using Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758852/angular-4-using-google-analytics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it from Angular then you need to do the whole thing from Angular.

```
// ga.ts
declare const ga: any;

export function startAnalytics(token) {
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);

        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

  ga('create', token, 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
}

// whatever.ts
import { startAnalytics } from './ga.ts';

// here e.g. retrieving your token from backend or whatsoever work
// you want to be done before

startAnalytics('whatever token you want');
```

Actually I'm not really sure `ga('send', 'pageview');` is the thing you want in SPA however this is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just a little modification this line `i[r].l = 1 * new Date();` is throwing the error      ERROR in src/app/ga.ts(9,29): error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.