# How to check for undefined when function is defined in a external JavaScript libs? (Angular4/5)

Tags: angular

In Angular 4 I'm using Google Analytics and I have the common error "ga is not defined".
This problem is NOT specific for Google Analytics, the third party JavaScript lib can be everything, CanvasJS, PayPal ...

The error is thrown only when I use it too early (in the ngInit for example), it is fine when I call it on the function of some event.

HTML page

```
<script>
    window.ga = window.ga || function () { (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments) }; ga.l = +new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-......', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview', "home");
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
```

My Component .ts file

```
declare let ga: Function

@Component({...})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        ga("send", "event", ...)
    }
}
```

I tried:

- `ga && ga("send", "event", ...)`
- `if(ga !== undefined) ga("send", "event", ...)`

I still have the noisy JavaScript error in the browser.

With  `try { ga("send", "event", ...) }     catch (error) { }` I can hide the error but I prefer a proper check.
I also don't want to remove the "async" from the JavaScrit load.

How can I check if **ga** (or whatever is the external lib) is defined ?

---

### Solved

As suggested by @Hien Nguyen:

```
// when called from ngInit "ga" is still not defined
if(typeof ga === "function") 
    ga('send', 'event', ...)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4+ using Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758852/angular-4-using-google-analytics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `typeof ga === 'function'`

```
@Component({...})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  ga: Function;
  ngOnInit() {
    if (typeof this.ga === 'function') {
      this.ga("send", "event", "");
    }
  }
}
```

Demo without exception in console https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6t8kza

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML page declare analytics.js first and then rest of your code.

```
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<script>
window.ga = window.ga || function () { (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments) }; ga.l = +new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-......', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview', "home");
</script>
```

Comment: It is loaded with __async__ (and I've no reason to change it) so I think it could not work (I'ven't tried).