# Embed Google Analytics real-time report in Angular web-app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-analytics

Now that I've added Google Analytics to my Angular web-app, I was wondering whether it's possible to embed Google Analytic's realtime report to my own website?

Since I haven't found any straight answer on the web, I'm asking here.

In case there is - how can I do so?

That's how I added Analytics:

```
<script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
      i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
      i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
      }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
      a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.async = 1;
      a.src = g;
      m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'myid', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/55981631/4964569

Comment: @HienNguyen I have it working, all I want is to display the report on my own web-app.