# Use environement variable in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using angular and I want to use an environment variable in my index.html for google analytics. I tried like this :

```
<script>
    import {environment} from "./environments/environment";
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=" + environment.googleAnalytics></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());


    gtag('config', environment.googleAnalytics);
</script>
```

But not working in the link of script. Can you help me please ? In this place `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=" + environment.googleAnalytics` didn't work this concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Need to add google anlytics in your dependencies and then add your tracking code to index.html as discussed in following link.

```
npm install --save @types/google.analytics
```

This link may helps to find a solution. Go through this thread.

[Angular 4+ using Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758852/angular-4-using-google-analytics)

Answer (score 0):

You can't write such concatenation because `<script>` is an html tag, it is not JavaScript code. Maybe you'll want to load that script through javascript, in that way you can concatenate your `environment.googleAnalytics` property.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be to have different `index.html` files (`index.dev.html`, `index.prod.html` etc.) in which you explicitly define the needed environment variables. Then, using the file replacement feature, switch between them (same way that the environment files are replaced).

```
"fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/index.html",
        "with": "src/index.prod.html"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a copy of index.html and name it index.someenv.html. Then in your angular.json in environment configuration setup file replacement:

```
"fileReplacements": [{
    "replace": "src/index.html",
    "with": "src/index.someenv.html"
}]
```

The angular cli will replace these files when you run your build