# How to Send page load time to Google analytics in angular 6/7/8

Tags: angular, typescript, google-analytics

currently, I am using google analytics for this I have followed [codeburst](https://codeburst.io/using-google-analytics-with-angular-25c93bffaa18) blog and everything is working fine, only I am stuck with page load time, If I am not wrong on every page load analytics.js sends page load time(plt) which is ok for multiple page application but I have SPA (angular 6) application on route change it is not sending page load time just because it is not reloading. I have used below code in the script tag right after head tag of index.html file

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
 i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
  i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
  }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
  a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
 })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js', 'ga'); ga('create','UA-14XXXXX-1',  {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100})
```

And in app.component.ts file, I am using

```
   this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    const urlList = event.urlAfterRedirects.split('?');
      (<any>window).ga('set', 'page', urlList[0]);
      (<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
});
```

This code giving time taken by landing page only but not working for route pages and showing as 0 page load time on google analytics.
Please let me know how I can send the time taken by every page to load completely.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4+ using Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758852/angular-4-using-google-analytics)

Comment: You are expected to do at least a little of your own research before posting questions.

Comment: @KurtHamilton, I have added my findings

Comment: Thanks. You also raise a good question. I've not looked into it myself, but I'm interested in the answer. To answer it we must first ask what defines the page load time in a SPA? Is it time from navigation ending to the last component rendering? I'd be surprised if there aren't several articles about this already. Sounds like a good subject for some more research :)