# Which is the best npm package for performing google analytics for an angular application?

Tags: angular, npm, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a requirement for including google analytics for my angular 8 project. Can anyone suggest me the best npm package available to implement analytics from client side ? I have seen many packages, but would be happy to get a genuine response from a developer who have used one of those .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at [Angular-GA](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/angular-ga). Although not mature it has a limited but decent API for events and pageviews with easy configuration.

Another approach might be to directly include `analytics.js` in your `index.html` and create a service that you can inject into your components directly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46463247/8156082) answer describes the process in detail.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen the approach using analytics.js and the answer you have highlighted. In that case, we have to include script tag with the data inside it. It looks messed up and as a good practise , its not advisable to use script tags in angular app. Thats why thought of looking a package from npm. Coming to Angular-GA , it doesnt have analytics tracking script included in the package. I will have to rely on some other package inorder to get additional features.

Comment: A script tag is also just JS code. You can put the same in a file and require it like a module to include GA in your application. Using `@types/google.analytics` from npm can be used to add type annotations for this new module. This way you can extend this simple module to have any functionality you need.